# java.lang.LinkageError: attempted duplicate class definition

Tags: java, linkageerror

Why does the error happen and how do I fix it?

```
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]: Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-2" 
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/bukkit/plugin/java/PluginClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/mongodb/client/model/Filters"
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getClassByName(JavaPluginLoader.java:195)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:97)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at me.franzsan.data.mongo.MongoCharacter.existsCharacter(MongoCharacter.java:109)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at me.franzsan.data.mongo.MongoCharacter.lambda$loadCharacter$0(MongoCharacter.java:44)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[02:13:02] [pool-4-thread-2/WARN]:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the line that causes the error

```
FindIterable cursor = connection.getCharacters().find(Filters.eq("uuid", uuid));
```

And then there is also this. It's from another module and both should be executed asynchronously at the same time (or shortly after one another, because I think right now I have only one thread). This one works without error.

```
FindIterable cursor = connection.getPlayers().find(Filters.eq("uuid", id));
```

Filters.eq is a static method.

Both are using the same

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

I feel like i'm lacking crucial knowledge, but I have no idea where to look fo rit.

Comment: Are you using some unusual classloading setup?

Comment: i'm using an interface for MongoCharacter class and a very similar one for MongoPlayer class (the class from the code that works). Is the MongoCharacter class the problem or is there something wrong with loading the Mongo driver? Both getPlayers() and getCharacters() are MongoCollection s which derive from the same MongoDatabase class

Comment: @ImranAli This is not a subclass of `LinkageError`. It *is* a `LinkageError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duplicate class definition for name` says all. It seems that you copied the mongodb driver in you plugin under the classpath `com.mongodb.client` like in your other plugin and you are running both plugins on the same server. This causes a conflict, because you attempt to load 2 classes with the exact same classpath.

Comment: I think it is a ClassLoader error. I fixed this error with putting db access in only one module. But later encountered the same problem with my own classes, when another module which had a dependency on a module loaded that module's class first (async). I load that enum manually on startup now