# Attempted duplicate class definition exception when inserting data class to MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

I'm doing some Spring Data document insertions in scheduled task, like this:

```kotlin
val session = client.startSession()
val template = MongoTemplate(client, db)
val sessionBoundOps = template.withSession(session)
session.startTransaction()
sessionBoundOps.insert(obj);
session.commitTransaction()
```

Which leads to the following exception:

```
Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @5d3411d attempted duplicate class definition for pw.prj.core.domain.stats.UserDailyStats_Accessor_wvhcc8. (pw.prj.core.domain.stats.UserDailyStats_Accessor_wvhcc8 is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @5d3411d, parent loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.createAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.potentiallyCreateAndRegisterPersistentPropertyAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:455)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.IdPropertyIdentifierAccessor.<init>(IdPropertyIdentifierAccessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getIdentifierAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:471)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$AdaptibleMappedEntity.of(EntityOperations.java:619)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$AdaptibleMappedEntity.access$100(EntityOperations.java:598)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations.forEntity(EntityOperations.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1170)
    at pw.prj.core.infra.persistence.MongoUserDailyStatsPersister$saveStatsAndTransferMoney$1.invoke(MongoUserDailyStatsPersister.kt:44)
    at pw.prj.core.infra.persistence.MongoUserDailyStatsPersister$saveStatsAndTransferMoney$1.invoke(MongoUserDailyStatsPersister.kt:18)
    at pw.prj.core.infra.TransactionRunner.run(TransactionRunner.kt:20)
    ...
```

My model is the simple data class, looks like this:

```kotlin
@Document
@CompoundIndexes(value = [
    CompoundIndex(def = "{'userId': 1, 'date': 1}", unique = true)
])
data class UserDailyStats(
    val userId: ObjectId,
    val date: Date,

    val viewsPerOwnServer: Map<String, Int>,
    val adViewsPerOwnServer: Map<String, Int>,
    val revenuePerOwnServer: Map<String, String>,

    val referralRegistrations: Int,
    val referralViews: Int,
    val referralAdViews: Int,
    val referralRevenue: String,

    @Id val id: String? = null
)
```

Java 12, Spring Boot 2.2.0.M5. Do you have any idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be related to this  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558290/java-lang-linkageerror-attempted-duplicate-class-definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me is to use common class instead of data class. Also changed `id` field type to `var` because of Spring complaints about final property.

**Update**: Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE fixes this as well, so it's still possible to use data classes for entities in multi-connection Spring environments.